# CSS ReactJS - div not setting his height to full

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a navbar and a component that needs to fill the remaining space of the screen height.

[image]
Green - the result I want to get
Blue - how it looks right now.

I have tried to set the height to h-screen but it doesn't work too... (its overfitting)
I am using *tailwind* for CSS

**Home.tsx**

```
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import Cart from './components/Cart';

    export default function Home() {
      return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="flex h-full">
            <Cart />
          </div>
    
        </main>
      )
    }
```

**Cart.tsx**

```
export default function Cart() {
  return (
    <div className="w-1/5 p-5 text-left border h-full">
        <p>הסל קניות שלי</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider applying `flex-grow: 1` to the `<div>` wrapper of `<Cart>` so that the `<div>` wrapper grows in height to the remainder of the screen height not occupied by `<NavBar>`. Then, remove `height: 100%` from the `<Cart>` root level `<div>` so that the default `align-items: stretch` takes effect, allowing the `<Cart>` root level `<div>` to be the height of the `<div>` wrapper of `<Cart>`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<main class="flex min-h-screen flex-col">
  <Navbar>Navbar</Navbar>

  <div class="flex grow">
    <div class="w-1/5 p-5 text-left border">
      <p>הסל קניות שלי</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```